# Bootstrap carousel disable sliding for specific element using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to disable slide for specific div element remaining should work accordingly. This is the code

```
<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
  <div class="" style="background-color: #50d2c2;">
    <video videoid="{{id}}" videotype="{{type}}" ng-if="isVideo"></video>
    <carousel>
      <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" carousel-index="slideIndex" active="slide.active" ng-animate="false">
        <div class="row">
          <div style="color: white; margin-top: 10px;text-align:center;">{{slide.name}}</div>
          <div style="color: white;font-size: 25px;margin-top: 20px;text-align:center;">{{slide.text}}</div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 160px;">
          <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
            <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;" href="#myCarousel"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2 glyphicon glyphicon-play" ng-model="playButton" ng-click="playVideo(slide);" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
            <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;" href="#myCarousel"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </slide>
    </carousel>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/XxPzW/134/

Here, I want to display **glyphicon-chevron-left, right play** icons below the **carousel-indicators** and slide shold be disable for this icons. Any help?